# How to make access denied for accessing image via browser url in magento2?

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento2, access-denied, folder-permissions

I want to make access denied for media (Images access) all user except admin. The user can not able to see any images via URL. Admin can check the user's uploaded images from admin panel only. 
please help me with solutions

Thanks

Comment: Who upvotes this? You should really be posting what you have so far, we're probably not gonna code this for you.

Comment: @kerbholz It is an obvious logical concept. I need suggestion How I can manage stuff. Without trying no sense to ask on so.